# How to detect when mouse 1 button is pressed then run a bash script?

Tags: python, bash

I want to detect when mouse 1 is clicked then run a script and every time mouse 1 is clicked it will run that script. I've tried to look at using python and bash but I am a beginner and don't know much.

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=$(date +¨%F_%I:%M:%S¨)

raspistill -o /home/pi/Pictures/$DATE.jpg -n -t 1 
scrot /home/pi/Pictures/$DATE.png
```

this is the script i'm trying to run and I've looking into, xev, xkeybinds xdotool but i just can't figure it out.

What we are trying to do is use a touchscreen monitor and every time is clicked it will take a photo.

Thank you

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106736/detect-if-mouse-button-is-pressed-then-invoke-a-script-or-command

Comment: I did look at that but i couldn't figure out how to change the code to get it to run my script :c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mouse="$(xinput --list | awk -F 'id=|\\[' '/mouse|Mouse/ {print $2}')"
mouse="${mouse//[[:space:]]}"

while :; do
    state="$(xinput --query-state "$mouse")"

    # If mouse 1 pressed.
    if [[ "$state" == *"button[1]=down"* ]]; then
        date="$(date +"%F_%I:%M:%S")"

        raspistill -o "/home/pi/Pictures/${date}.jpg" -n -t 1 2>/dev/null &
        scrot "/home/pi/Pictures/${date}-2.jpg" &
    fi

sleep .1s
done
```

Comment: Decent answer, even simpler than https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171583/310042